# Twitter Bootstrap Javascript - how to use only tooltip library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a project that is without Twitter Bootstrap. I would like to use [Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips), so I downloaded **bootstrap-tooltip.js** file, put it to the page. (there is included jQuery lib as well).

And this is how I am trying to call tooltip:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.tooltip_link').tooltip();
});
<a href="www.something.com" class="tooltip_link" data-original-title="tooltip text">www.something.com</a>
```

But the tooltip will never appear, in console log are no JS errors. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-toggle="tooltip"` maybe?
I've tried to reproduce what you have here, after inserting this I got it working ([JSfiddle right here](http://jsfiddle.net/JnShg/)).

In the docs you've referenced there's the following code:

`<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">hover over me</a>`

Comment: Is there also needed to include Bootstrap CSS or another Bootstrap JS?

Comment: Well, you **do** need bootstrap CSS in order to get the styling. Open JSfiddle, remove bootstrap CSS and try it. You will get it working, but that's probably not the way you want. Bare bootstrap and a tooltip library + CSS should be enough.